# Bool is returning an array causing true response every time in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting a true return with very query in Laravel 5.2. I am making query in the controller and returning an array.

```
 if($term = $request->get('term')){

          $booking = guests::where('booking', '=', $term)->get(); 
          $active =  guests::where('booking', '=', $term)->pluck('active');

      }          
    // dd($active);

      if($active){
          echo '
```

I have read it could potentially be solved by attribute casting by attempts have not worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both get() and pluck() will return a collection, so making an if condition like the one you are doing - will not return false even if a collection is completely empty (collection method isEmpty() would return false though). The result of `if ($active)` in your code has nothing to do with the value of the 'active' field itself.

You can try adding first() to the chain, assuming that you only have or you only need one item:

```
$booking = guests::where('booking', '=', $term)->get()->first();
$active =  guests::where('booking', '=', $term)->pluck('active')->first();
```

Comment: @Jeff was within the minute, then left my computer. Chill!

Comment: it wont return false even if the collection is empty btw, object == true.